# I/O error while compiling delphi code

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-7

I have a delphi project in a folder say MyProject. It was compiling fine. But when I changed the folder name to MyProject1 from MyProject, it gave me error "I/O Error" while compiling. How should I fix it. I just renamed the folder.

Comment: Close the project, open it from the renamed folder. Compile it and have a nice day ;-)

Comment: @TLama - It didn't work :(

Comment: So is it Delphi 7 or Delphi-XE2 ? those are different programs.

Tell as more details, which error exactly and on which exactly file does it happen. If you cannot figure out  by error text, use file i/o log from SysInternals Process Monitor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I caught the error. While compiling the exe file say myExe.exe, it was taking the path C:\MyProject1\myExe.exe but while linking it was taking previous path like C:\MyProject\myExe.exe. I went on Project -> Options -> Output directory. There output directory was mentioned like this: C:\MyProject but when I changed it to C:\MyProject1, it worked.

Comment: That's why it's better to use relative path. You could make a folder like `..\bin` and set the output there...

Comment: Or not specify a path at all, in which case the .EXE file is output to the same directory as the .dpr file, no matter where it is loaded from...

Comment: ... unless version is XEx, then it is stuffed in the platform- and build-dependant subdirectory ".\$(Platform)\$(Config)". But since that's relative it will still work. Personally I find it a pain that I have to dig two levels deeper for my EXE when not running it from the IDE, so I clear this (making only Win32 exes).

Comment: @Jan, if you don't want to to that two levels, remove the $(platform) from your output config and enjoy!.